# How do I programmatically pull an item from a Celery queue?

Tags: python, celery

I have a Celery queue where I want to programmatically pull the next item from the queue based on certain triggers, etc.

If I have a task defined as

```
@task
def my_task():
    do_stuff()
```

and then place items in the queue via

```
my_task.apply_async()
```

Celery will crank through the items in the queue as fast as it can. But what I'd like to be able to do is something like:

```
my_task.process_next()
```

Is there any way to control when Celery pulls stuff from a queue?

Comment: Python module names are hilarious.

Comment: are you trying to find how to remove the task from the queue?

Comment: @grrrrrr - Yes, I'm trying to remove it and then process it, but on MY schedule rather than an automatic, fast-as-it-can-get-to-it schedule.

Answer (score 1):

Celery very reasonably assumes that once something is on the queue you want it processed as soon as possible. [there is the countdown argument](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown) but I guess that's not what you want.

You could try overriding the [Task Class](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#custom-task-classes) and putting some logic in the `__call__` method to check if you really want to process the task and then maybe schedule it for retry if it turns out it's not ready for processing by your schedule.

Comment: Thanks @scytale. The countdown arg isn't exactly what I was looking for, but it may be helpful in getting me at least part of the way there.  I wasn't aware of that one.